# Php unserialize string

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

When I do `var_dump($string);` I get

```
string(894) "[{"id":"11","value":"Gotowy do u\u017cytku"},{"id":"12","value":"Na 4 k\u00f3\u0142kach"},{"id":"13","value":"20 minut - rozgrzany do pracy"},{"id":"14","value":"Pow. u\u017cytkowa 108 cm2"},{"id":"15","value":"Piec i grill w jednym"},{"id":"16","value":["tekst","\/images\/alfa\/domowa\/forninox\/1.jpg","lightbox"]},{"id":"17","value":["tekst","\/images\/alfa\/domowa\/forninox\/1.jpg","lightbox"]},{"id":"18","value":["tekst","\/images\/alfa\/domowa\/forninox\/3.jpg","lightbox"]},{"id":"19","value":["tekst","\/images\/alfa\/domowa\/forninox\/2.jpg","lightbox"]},{"id":"20","value":"cm 127"},{"id":"21","value":"cm 189"},{"id":"22","value":"cm2 108"},{"id":"23","value":"Kg 340"},{"id":"24","value":"\u00a6 cm 25\/20"},{"id":"25","value":"Mat. ceramiczny"},{"id":"26","value":"Stal nierdzewna"},{"id":"27","value":"W\u0142. ceramiczne"},{"id":"28","value":"min 20"},{"id":"29","value":"7"}]"
```

and I what to put this string into array, so I do unserialize, like this:

```
$a = unserialize($string); 
var_dump($a);
```

But in the output I get:

```
bool(false)
```

Enybody knows what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a json string. You want to use

```
$arr = json_decode($string, TRUE);
```

to deserialize it to an associative array.

Comment: Thank you very much, how did you recognize that is a json string?

Comment: Note this would not deserialize into an associate array, but rather a numerically indexed array. JSON has no concept of an associative array.

Comment: @MikeBrant php does have a concept of an associative array, though. If he used this solution, he could reference "tekst" by using $arr[5]["value"][0]. This key,value, dictionary-type referencing is the same as a php associative array.

Comment: @MikeBrant Here is the php reference to json_decode http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Yes, but truly this is a numerically indexed array of objects.  The main enclosing array is a numerically indexed array not an associative array. You also cannot use ArrayAccess on the `stdClass` object that would be created for each value in the array. So your example would have to be `$arr[5]->value[0]`

Comment: @MikeBrant I was just going off of the definition in the documentation and for the 2nd argument it says "When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays."

Comment: @eliot Yes sorry, I was not even paying attention to the fact that your had the option flag in there :P My bad.

Comment: @MikeBrant No worries. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't crazy!

Answer (score 0):

It's not serialized, but json encoded. Use:

```
$decoded = json_decode($string);
```